# Need to hide an <hr> when jQuery slideToggle is executed, then show when clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am starting to learn jQuery. I have a simple button that I have executing slideToggle to show/hide a div. I have an

---

break line above the div being toggled. I need to hide this

---

when the button is first clicked to toggle the div open, then need to show the

---

when the button is clicked again to toggle the div closed. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is my code as well as a simple jsfiddle example.

https://jsfiddle.net/ewsrq961/1/

Thank you.

HTML:

```
<hr id="hrItem">
<div id="actionItems">
<h2>Hello There!</h2>
</div>

<div id="actionsBtn">
    <a id="btnAction" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="tooltip" title="Open Actions" class="btn faa-vertical animated-hover" data-original-title="Open Actions"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>Actions</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#actionItems {
    display: none;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#actionsBtn {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #252d44;
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff !important;
    padding:5px;
}
#actionsBtn a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

JS:

```
// Hide/Show div
        $("#btnAction").click(function(){
            $("#actionItems").slideToggle();
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-circle-down fa-chevron-circle-up')
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to show it when the div is closed and hide when the div is option then you can just call `.toggle()` function on click and it will hide on first click and show on each second click.

```
$('#hrItem').toggle();
```

**Example:**

```js
// Hide/Show Actions Panel
$("#btnAction").click(function(){
    $("#actionItems").slideToggle();
    $('#hrItem').toggle();    //ADDED
    $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-circle-down fa-chevron-circle-up')
});
```

```css
#actionItems {
    display: none;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#actionsBtn {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #252d44;
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff !important;
    padding:5px;
}
#actionsBtn a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr id="hrItem">
<div id="actionItems">
  <h2>Hello There!</h2>
</div>

<div id="actionsBtn">
  <a id="btnAction" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="tooltip" title="Open Actions" class="btn faa-vertical animated-hover" data-original-title="Open Actions"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>Actions</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

While you have id `#hrItem` to `hr` so its simple to add css style for it with `display : none;` and then add `#hrItem` to classes to `slideToggle` in js code

```js
// Hide/Show Actions Panel
$("#btnAction").click(function(){
  $("#actionItems , #hrItem").slideToggle();   //<<<< add hr id
  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-circle-down fa-chevron-circle-up')
});
```

```css
#hrItem{   /* style hr*/
  display : none;
}
#actionItems {
    display: none;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#actionsBtn {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #252d44;
    width: 120px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff !important;
    padding:5px;
}
#actionsBtn a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<hr id="hrItem">
<div id="actionItems">
  <h2>Hello There!</h2>
</div>

<div id="actionsBtn">
  <a id="btnAction" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="tooltip" title="Open Actions" class="btn faa-vertical animated-hover" data-original-title="Open Actions">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>
    Actions
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a conditional in the click event that would adjust the `<hr/>` based on visibility:

```js
// Hide/Show Actions Panel
$("#btnAction").click(function() {
  $('#hrItem').is(':visible') ? $('#hrItem').hide() : $('#hrItem').show();

  $("#actionItems").slideToggle();

  $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-circle-down fa-chevron-circle-up');
});
```

```css
#actionItems {
  display: none;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#actionsBtn {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #252d44;
  width: 120px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #fff !important;
  padding: 5px;
}

#actionsBtn a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<hr id="hrItem">
<div id="actionItems">
  <h2>Hello There!</h2>
</div>

<div id="actionsBtn">
  <a id="btnAction" href="javascript:void(0)" rel="tooltip" title="Open Actions" class="btn faa-vertical animated-hover" data-original-title="Open Actions"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 10px;"></i>Actions</a>
</div>
```